# PHP MYSQL while loop with if statement echoing in wrong order

Tags: php, mysql, loops, if-statement, while-loop

Ok, right now I trying to get a list to echo out from mysql using a while loop, but as you can see here http://institute4se.com/plan/ it's echoing in the wrong order. Why?

The reason for the if statements is to make the top and bottom pieces of the div echo only when the loop reaches the beginning of a new subsection.

If I remove the if statement the list echos out in order but then the beginning and end of the div echo every loop.

You can see my database aka $info here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMO2X.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsHdb.png

Any thoughts on how to fix it?

```
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 {

if($info['subsection']=='0'){
echo "
<div class='menuSection'>
<div class='sectionHeader' id='header".$info['section']."'><img src='images/status_circ_empty.gif' alt='Section Empty' /><a href='index.php?s=".$info['section']."&ss=".$info['subsection']."'>".$titleArr[$info['section']]."</a><img src='images/arrow_".$currentArrow.".gif' alt='Arrow' class='arrow' /></div>
    <ul class='sectionSubmenu' id='section".$info['section']."' style='display:".$currentSection."'>
"; 
}
else{
echo "<li><img src='images/status_circ_empty.gif' alt='Section Empty' /><a href='index.php?s=".$info['section']."&ss=".$info['subsection']."'>".$info['title']."</a></li>"; 
}
if($info['subsection']=='0'){
echo"
    </ul>
</div>
";
}
}
```

Comment: Isn't it just that you've got the line from the else duplicated in the main bit of the if? EDIT: Looks like you've removed that bit of code from your question, so I guess that wasn't it!

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: What's the underlying query you're running? Nothing in PHP will re-order the results unless you structure the code to make it come out wonky. So... probably your query is sorting wrong. If you're sorting by section ID numbers instead of section Name, you'll undoubtedly get "bad" ordering.

Comment: I'm not reordering anything, all I'm trying to so is have the div code echo every time the subsection in the mysql database is 0, meaning it has reached a new submenu list. The order I'm referring to is the order which it is echoing the if and else statements.

Comment: @Dave K: We neither know the structure/indexes of the table, nor do we know the query statement you use. It would be sort of helpful, if you'd at least show what `$info` contains. Otherwise we can only guess or use crystal balls^^

Comment: @Dave K, please refrain from vandalizing your own question.  If you wish to delete a question, try using the "delete" link below the list of tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fixed code for anyone who is interested:

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 

    // if the current subsection is a new section
    if($info['subsection']==0){
    // if the current section is NOT the first section
    if($info['section']!=0){
    // end the section div
    echo "
            </ul>
    </div>
    ";
    }

    // start the section div and add the section header
    echo "
    <div class='menuSection'>
    <div class='sectionHeader' id='header".$info['section']."'><img src='images/status_circ_empty.gif' alt='Section Empty' /><a href='index.php?s=".$info['section']."&ss=".$info['subsection']."'>".$titleArr[$info['section']]."</a><img src='images/arrow_".$currentArrow.".gif' alt='Arrow' class='arrow' /></div>
        <ul class='sectionSubmenu' id='section".$info['section']."' style='display:".$currentSection."'>
        <li><img src='images/status_circ_empty.gif' alt='Section Empty' /><a href='index.php?s=".$info['section']."&ss=".$info['subsection']."'>".$info['title']."</a></li>

    ";

    }
    // if the current section is not a new section
    else{
        // add the next submenu item
        echo "<li><img src='images/status_circ_empty.gif' alt='Section Empty' /><a href='index.php?s=".$info['section']."&ss=".$info['subsection']."'>".$info['title']."</a></li>"; 
    }
} 
echo"
    </ul>
</div>
";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to order records, add `ORDER BY subsection ASC` to the query.